# Drawing with SpriteBatch and GraphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives

Tags: xna, c#, windows-phone-7

I've faced with a problem when i tried to draw 2d game with `SpriteBatch` and `GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives`. I suppose that what is drawing with `SpriteBatch` has higher priority, because i can not see a result of its rendering. `GraphiscDevice.DrawUserPrimitives` renders only if i comment a line of rendering background. Here is my method Draw. Could you check the order of rendering. What is the reason?

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.BlanchedAlmond);    

    basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();

    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(background, new Rectangle { X = 0, Y = 0, Height = Bounds.Height, Width = Bounds.Width }, Color.White);

    DrawCell();
    spriteBatch.DrawString(defaultFont, "fps: " + FPS, new Vector2(10, 75), Color.DarkBlue);

    spriteBatch.End();

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}

private void DrawCell()
{
    basicEffect.Texture = cellBody;
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, cell.Triangles, 0, cell.Triangles.Length / 3);
}

protected override void Initialize()
{
    basicEffect = new BasicEffect(graphics.GraphicsDevice);
    basicEffect.TextureEnabled = true;
    basicEffect.Texture = bg_menu;
    basicEffect.World = Matrix.Identity;
    basicEffect.Projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter
  (0, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width,
  graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 0,
  0, 1);
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The spritebatch items don't actually draw onto the back buffer until spritebatch.End() is called. This is so it knows which sprites to 'batch' into 1 call to the GPU.

So your code basically:

1. informs the spritbatch that `background` will be one item in the
   batch
2. draws `Drawcell` directly to the back buffer (because you call it explicitly)
3. informs the spritebatch that `"fps: "` will be another item in the batch
4. `End()` is call so it batches and draws `background` and `"fps: "` to the back
   buffer overwriting the `DrawCell` stuff

It is generally recommended to `End()` the spritebatch before explicitly calling directly from the graphics device.

Comment: i have tried to call SpriteBatch.End(),but the notification about mistake appears
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Are you saying that SpriteBatch.Draw uses the GPU out of the box? Really?

Comment: I don't know. I've tried to run code as you've told, but i am not succeed, that's why i'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this issue in my game recently, however I found the way to get over it is to call end before your draw primatives and begin after it:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.BlanchedAlmond);    

basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();

spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.Draw(background, new Rectangle { X = 0, Y = 0, Height = Bounds.Height, Width = Bounds.Width }, Color.White);

spriteBatch.End(); //end the spritebatch here 
DrawCell();
spriteBatch.Begin(); // start it again here
spriteBatch.DrawString(defaultFont, "fps: " + FPS, new Vector2(10, 75), Color.DarkBlue);

spriteBatch.End();

base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: Yes, guys. I've tryied to do it in such ways also, but it doesn't help

Comment: do you mind putting in the code for the definition od `cell` and `cellbody`. Also `BasicEffect` is only ever assigned to and never used, is it used somewhere else not in your demo code?  I am thinking that there is something else going wrong here.